# How To Display Part of Excel on VBA Form

Tags: excel, excel-2007, userform, vba

I have a file on .csv format and from A-S columns, it has some records like a table. My complete program will insert/remove/delete/add some rows, columns and editing cell values etc. I managed to code all the operations that i need, now i'm trying to integrate it with a gui.

What I want is to display cells from Ax1 to the last column that has record on VBA user form. How can i do that?

*ps: again, my file's format is .csv and I am using Excel 2007

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a multi column Listbox to show the data.

**LOGIC**

1. Import the text (Csv) file in the temp sheet
2. Show that data in the multicolumn Listbox
3. Delete the temp sheet in the Userform unload event

**Import the text (Csv) file in the temp sheet**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyCsv.Csv")

    wbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

    Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet

    wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

And now you can display that data in a multicolumn listbox.

**Show that data in the multicolumn Listbox**

I am taking an example of 3 Columns and up till tow 20. Change as applicable

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyCsv.Csv")

    wbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)


    Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet

    wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=False

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"
        .RowSource = wsTemp.Range("A1:C20").Address
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

**Delete the temp sheet in the Userform unload event**

To Delete the temp sheet, declare the `wsTemp` on the top of the code so that you can access that in the `UserForm_QueryClose` event. See this complete example

```
Option Explicit

Dim wsTemp As Worksheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyCsv.Csv")

    wbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)


    Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet

    wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=False

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"
        .RowSource = wsTemp.Range("A1:C20").Address
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: nice one. I just want to clarify one doubt, i.e. can we display different set of ranges such as Range("A1:E1") headers and followed by any range below it range("A20:E25")?