# Excel VBA string WIDTH

Tags: string, excel, width, vba

In excel string length not equal to string size same length string with diff characters (spaces) looks shorter each other.

So then I trying to align two columns in drop down list I get result as in picture below in cell HAVE I need to do like in cell NEED

[image]

So how to get string width but not length?

Comment: It's kind of complex as it depends not only on the font that you are using but also on the screen resolution.

Comment: so how to get list box with multi column so in first column values from first column in second list column get values from second column?

Comment: You can use multi column listbox with a predefined width. I have already answered a similar question few (or maybe more) months back

Comment: give a link for example please

Comment: Something like [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527540/how-to-display-part-of-excel-on-vba-form/13529898#13529898)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use monospace font (courier, consolas, lucida console etc).
This will do.